# Resolve promises from a loop with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

So a XHR is run inside a loop and I would like to execute a function after all the XHR complete, I tried this with promises as follows.

```
var promises = [];
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    promise = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : data_url,
                    data:pdata
    });
    promises.push(promise);
}
$.when(promises).then(function(){
                window.location.href = '/cart?edit_order=true'
})
```

The problem is the redirect happens before the AJAX is completed, what am I missing?

Comment: I saw that you specified jQuery in the title, but just for history purposes, you can do this in a "better" way and by better i mean better readability and extensibility. 

    `q.all([loadSomething(), loadAnotherThing()])
        .spread(function(something, another) {
            DoSomethingOnThem(something, another);
    });` 

Where `loadSomething(), loadAnotherThing()` are two promises and `q.all` is from the following promise library : https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, jQuery's `.when()` method didn't accept an *Array* of promises as argument, but single arguments instead. That just means you need to change the way of invoking it to:

```
$.when.apply( null, promises ).then(function(){
            window.location.href = '/cart?edit_order=true'
})
```

Using `Function.prototype.apply` will automatically take an *Array* and put each value of that *Array* as single arguments into the invoked function, in this case, `.when()`. Effectively spreading the arguments.

You can also do some EMCAscript magic and create a little partial application for that:

```
var when = Function.prototype.apply.bind( $.when, null );
```

..and then just call

```
when( promises ).then(function() { ...
```

Comment: You mean apply, which spreads the arguments?

Comment: You can also use `$.when(..promises)` in recent versions of ES

Comment: Sure, but you "can" also use native promises and arrow functions and everything, but then you should strongly advice the usage of a pre- or transpiler. Destructering is not widely supported in browser versions for now.

Comment: Yeah, transpiling can be complicated... but the point is that it's a very elegant way. "In recent versions" was intended as the advice you just stated.